# Current position of Java Language Conversion Assistant and J#

Tags: c#, java

[A recent answer to a question  on converting Java to C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508019/identifying-code-that-compiles-in-both-java-and-c-but-runs-differently) suggested I should use Java Language Conversion Assistant and pointed to:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tatw8a2%28VS.80%29.aspx

I cannot find JLCA on my Visual Studio (9.0.30729.1) and on looking at Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J_Sharp) I find:

> Retirement of the J# language and Java
>   Language Conversion Assistant from
>   future versions of Visual Studio,
>   since the existing J# feature set
>   largely meets customer needs and usage
>   of J# is declining. The last version
>   shipping with Visual Studio 2005 will
>   be supported until 2015 as per the
>   product life-cycle strategy.

I'd be grateful for an overview of whether I can use and should be using either J# or JLCA and if so how to install and use them.

Comment: That seems so ill-advised.  Just manually re-write in C# and make sure you have enough tests first!  Either that or stick with Java and have the freedom to run your stuff on Linux, OS-X, or your cell phone.  J# is just the worst of both worlds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this and other answers it seems that J# should be deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Something that might help - there is an open source project [IKVM.Net](http://www.ikvm.net/) that can recompile your java bytecode into .net byte code. Afterwards, you could use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to decompile the generated .net assembly into C# for additional modifications. IKVM comes with a fully converted java class library as .net assembly, which you can continue using from that code, while slowly moving to the core .net libraries.